# He may be wondering

Tags: american-english

Suppose i gave a gift to my friend and im talking to myself in my mind

**He may be wondering what is in it.**

is this correct way of saying or i should say

1.He may be wondering what will/(would) be in it.

2.He might be wondering wha would be in it.

Comment: Not all those who wander are lost.

Comment: As regards whether his curiosity concerns ***what is / will be / would be / might be in the box***, it's syntactically irrelevant whether he may/might be wondering, or actually ***is wondering***. So to some extent I'd say this is two separate questions mashed together.

Comment: If he's wondering, he hasn't opened it yet and so the contents are still in it (so it's 'what is').

Comment: What exactly is "it"? Is it the gift? Why would there be anything in it? He should be wondering what it is. Or what's in the box, if a box were mentioned. Or whether it's alive, if he's into quantum mechanics...

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is correct, although unless you’re specifically talking about a parcel that contains something, it would be enough to say “He may be wondering what it is.”

Such sentences follow the [rules for reported speech](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/). “You do not need to change the tense if the reporting verb is in the present …”:

> He potentially thinks: “What is in it?”
>
> You say: He may be wondering what is in it.

“… or if the original statement is about something that is still true”:

> He potentially thought: “What is in it?”
>
> You say: He may have been wondering what was in it. [ - if the gift has since been opened]
>
> Or: He may have been wondering what is in it. [ - if the gift still hasn't been opened]